# Is it possible to have a scope with optional arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

Is it possible to write a scope with optional arguments so that i can call the scope with and without arguments?

Something like:

```
scope :with_optional_args,  lambda { |arg|
  where("table.name = ?", arg)
}

Model.with_optional_args('foo')
Model.with_optional_args
```

I can check in the lambda block if an arg is given (like described by Unixmonkey) but on calling the scope without an argument i got an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. Just use a `*` like you would in a method.

```
scope :print_args, lambda {|*args|
    puts args
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Ruby 1.9 extended blocks to have the same features as methods do (default values are among them):

```
scope :cheap, lambda{|max_price=20.0| where("price < ?", max_price)}
```

Call:

```
Model.cheap
Model.cheap(15)
```

Answer (score 14):

I used `scope :name, ->(arg1, arg2 = value) { ... }` a few weeks ago, it worked well, if my memory's correct. To use with ruby 1.9+

Answer (score 13):

You can conditionally modify your scope based on a given argument.

```
scope :random, ->(num = nil){ num ? order('RANDOM()').limit(num) : order('RANDOM()') }
```

Usage:

```
Advertisement.random # => returns all records randomized
Advertisement.random(1) # => returns 1 random record
```

Or, you can provide a default value.

```
scope :random, ->(num = 1000){ order('RANDOM()').limit(num) }
```

Usage:

```
Product.random # => returns 1,000 random products
Product.random(5) # => returns 5 random products
```

NOTE: The syntax shown for `RANDOM()` is specific to Postgres. The syntax shown is Rails 4.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to let you know that according to the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), the recommended way for passing arguments to scopes is to use a class method, like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.1_week_before(time)
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  end
end
```

This can give a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.

```
scope :with_optional_args,  Proc.new { |arg|
  if arg.present?
    where("table.name = ?", arg)
  end
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to include a fallback for when no args are passed?

Comment: I got an error if i do not pass an argument: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: You could use Proc.new instead of lambda to avoid the argument error. See this old discussion on this [here](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/90-enhancement-add-support-for-named-scopes-with-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *

```
scope :with_optional_args,  -> { |*arg| where("table.name = ?", arg) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object#then` (or `Object#yield_self`, they are synonyms) for this. For instance:

```rb
scope :cancelled, -> (cancelled_at_range = nil) { joins(:subscriptions).merge(Subscription.cancelled).then {|relation| cancelled_at_range.present? ? relation.where(subscriptions: { ends_at: cancelled_at_range }) : relation } }
```